# how to install bluestacks on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: software-installation

Am having a problem installing bluestacks on ubuntu 18.04 using wine,someone to help please with the procedure

Answer (score 1):

BlueStacks currently does not support Linux and will not work under Wine as it's an emulator.

Answer (score 1):

You may probably not be able to install BlueStacks on Ubuntu 18.04 *(and it's other distributions)*, neither on Wine, since it is just a windows compatibility layer and BlueStacks is an emulator... 
*(There are slight possibilities using 'another' tool such as 'Jar of Beans' as seen below)*.

However, there are some Android emulators that though aren't as stable as BlueStacks can still be made use of. I'll elaborate a little on these but you can Google more about them in order to find a complete solution to your problem. These are:

- **The Official Android SDK**

The official Android SDK (software development kit) is the best way to emulate Android on Linux Ubuntu. While there are many other emulators out there: some of them are very limited feature sets, some of them are paid, and some of them don’t even run.

The official Android SDK is made by Google for Android development and it supports all the functions including file transfer and SD Card support. One great thing about this android emulator is that it supports physical keypad which none of the other emulators do.

As it is developed by Google themselves, you can be sure that it won’t have a lot of problems. Even if there are some problems, the Google engineers will surely iron them out in no time at all. If you need a fast and official Android emulator on Linux, the official Android software development kit is the best way to go.

- **Genymotion**

Genymotion is one of the best Android emulators for Linux and comes with a lot of different features that are unique to it. It is designed well and works smoothly with the operating system. You’ll need to set up a virtual box in order to use it, we have listed the method to install it above.

You can easily download preconfigured Android images of different Android versions. It also gives you the flexibility of configuring the precise amount of resources you will be allotted. For example, if you want to set up the RAM at 3 GB, you can do so easily. You’ll also be able to allow hard disk storage space appropriately.

The app also supports networking through Wi-Fi and Ethernet. This means you’ll be able to use the Internet directly in the immolated Android apps and games. I was also pleasantly surprised to see that the app has full support for a gyroscope, accelerometer, and light sensors as well. Overall, it’s a complete package that won’t disappoint you at all. The only downside is that you’ll need to be connected to a cloud service to deploy Genymotion, so Internet connectivity is a must.

- **Andro VM**

Andro VM is what made Genymotion possible, it works almost the same and provides great functionality. The major difference between Andro VM and Genymotion is that it can be deployed off-line. This makes it highly convenient for those who have limited Internet access.

Of course, you also need to install virtual box on your machine in order to use Andro VM. The program supports net sharing from guest to host. Internet sharing is also available. One great thing about this Android emulator for Linux is that it supports hardware OpenGL rendering. In layman terms, this will enable you to play graphics intensive games without any worries.

Overall, it’s a great Linux Android emulator that runs apps and games smoothly on your Linux PC. Connecting to the Internet is no problem at all and you’ll have full access to the Internet while using emulated apps. It can be found on Genymotion website as well to download.

- **Jar of Beans**

Jar of Beans was designed to be an Android Emulator for Windows; however, you can also run it on Linux as well. But for that, you’ll need to install Wine, another emulator that runs Windows on Linux. So basically, you will be running Android apps on an Android emulator being run on a Windows emulator on Linux.

If you’re okay with going to this extent, Jar of Beans has all the basic support you’ll need. You can easily install APK files on it, it supports SD card, and even allows installation of the Google play store. Overall it’s a nifty little program that will allow you to run Android apps and games on your Linux device.

Of course, it is not as viable to use emulation within an emulator, because it will be taxing and there will be exponentially more chances of failure. But if you’re reading this article, you already know what you are doing, so I’ll leave it up to you. To run Jar of Beans download and extract the contents and then run it by using Wine.

---

*Content on the various Android emulators was taken from [joyofandroid.com](https://joyofandroid.com/android-emulators-for-linux/)* *